# What are good strategies in C for dealing with pointer errors of this type?

Tags: c, code-quality, debugging, pointers

In C, I often come across errors with code like this

```
prio_queue->head[index] = newEntry;
```

Yields a " "Cannot assign Entry** to Entry* "
How do you prevent/debug errors of this type, in general?

Comment: This is syntactically correct. What are the types and data structures, what error do you think you have? Need more information.....

Comment: The error was "Cannot assign Entry** to Entry* "

Comment: @Adel, you're lucky - it's one of the rare cases when the C compiler managed to find an error for you. What else do you need?

Comment: Huh? Just don't make such errors. And if you did, be happy the compiler found it and correct it. What else do you want to hear? Don't use C? But well, another language doesn't completely protect you from the burden of actually understanding what you do.

Comment: @ChristianRau - *Ouch* , Ok got it . good point thnx

Comment: @Adel Sorry, it may have been a bit harsh, but I just couldn't get the point of this question in any way.

Comment: You're right - And I need  to remember to provide more context, and think through the question, even on paper, before asking you guys. Because most of you are really smart. This is a specialized place after all! Hey I've learned my lesson, and am not offended/hurt. I'll be careful from now. Have a  nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If head is an array of elements, and index is < size of that array, and newEntry is of the same type as the array, and prio_queue is a pointer to a data structure containing head, then there nothing wrong with this code.

A lot of ifs, but without knowing your data structures, I (and no one else) can tell if it's right or wrong.

Update: 
Based on the update to the question, a strategy would be to keep careful track of how many levels of indirection a variable has.

Comment: " track of how many levels of indirection a variable"  - hmm, this suggests using paper & pencil to double-check. Which seems smart to me, thanks!

Comment: Paper is a bad way to go. Use variable naming conventions where appropriate (**Not** application Hungarian, descriptive names), and typedefs.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of problems you may run into:

1. The compilation level where pointer data types are not matching
2. The run time issues where array bounds overflows and hence either violates the memory access or corrupts the internal data structure which will result in memory problem later in the execution.

Your problem looks like compilation problem than run time so it looks more like data type mismatch problem mostly but we need more information to dig up this.
Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

I've been away from a C compiler for quite a few years, but isn't it telling you that prio_queue->head[index] is a pointer to Entry and newEntry is a pointer to a pointer to Entry?  Try:

prio_queue->head[index] = *newEntry;

Comment: This will fix the syntax error, however no one can say if it is correct. Given the question, I have my doubts......

Answer (score 0):

> How do you prevent/debug errors of this type, in general?

This particular issue comes down to knowing the types of the respective expressions, and there are no shortcuts to that; either you know it or you don't.  The question to answer is *why* the types are different in the first place; that indicates that someone was a bit confused when they wrote the code.